# how to create a link to an outside webpage with an automatic input in a field

Tags: http

I would like to create a hyperlink to the web page below and have the user see an automatic value in the text field. Is there anyway to do this?

https://secure.tuitionrewards.com/sp/index.cfm?p=e0&bpid=103&j=6974C&ref=&pro=&sr=

Comment: Is that external page set up to accept query string parameters or is it your page to where it can be set up to do so?

Comment: Hi Ryan, I don’t own the page I am linking to. What I want to accomplish is sending someone to that page and instead of telling them what number to input I was hoping there was some kind of Macro language to have that field populate. I was able to do something like that with Google reviews where I would send a user to my review page on Google and 5stars would automatically populate. So I was hoping for something like that in this instance.

Comment: The page needs to be set up to accept input for that to work and it did not appear to be. Your only other option would be a browser based marco, which obviously wouldn't work because it would be specific to each user's browser.